# Power shell - How I can activate the Cloud flows and check for the connections using power shell?

Tags: powershell, power-automate

Every time I deploy the solution to the target the changes are not reflected for the Cloud flows so below step I followed to activate the flows.

1. Remove the unmanaged layer from the Could flow solution.
2. Import the solutions to target the environment
3. Check for the all the cloud flows and make it off and on to see the connections are properly added or not.

these steps are manual for me. Need help how to automate these steps as the number of the flows are more.

Answer (score 0):

To turn flows on / off - active / inactive one can use the     [Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/?view=pa-ps-latest) and [Microsoft.PowerApps.PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell) modules. They are thoroughly documented and these can be used to turn cloud flows on and off again. With powershell you can automate this process.

Importing solutions to the target environment can be automated by using the [package deployer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/package-deployer-tool).

I am not sure how one is able to automate the removal of the unmanaged layer from the cloud flow solution. If I figure that out I will post back here.